# Working with multiple time ranges in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

An appointment system: many **rooms** have **bookings** during a specific day, and I need to build code that suggests **three 30-minute free times** to any user across those rooms.

Each `booking` has a `start_time` and `end_time`.

So, between the hours of 8am and 6pm on this one day, I need to collect all the `bookings`, isolate the times between those bookings' ranges, then choose three of those free times at random. Something like...

```
@bookings = Booking.where("room_id IN (?)", @rooms.collect(&:id))
@busy_times = @bookings.collect{|b| b.start_time..b.end_time}
@empty_times = (@day.end_time - @day.start_time) - @busy_times # so to speak
```

In general, I can do the coding necessary for this sort of problem, but I don't really know how to work effectively with multiple time ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I an not sure if there is any existed library method could do this. If I implement the feature, I may do it in following steps.

1. After get the books, convert the start and end time to epoch timestamp.
2. Sort the booking time range by start time, put each start and end time stamp to a array in the sorted sequence. Each element of the array is **[timestamp, flag]**. The flag could be **:start** or **:end**.
3. Traverse the array. Use a counter, e.g., count. If encounter a flag is :start, count++， if flag is :end, then count--. Then, if count==0 after a :end flag, until next :start, this time slot is free. If the time slot > 30 × 60，put the time slot to a array, e.g. free_time_slot_array.
4. Also check the time from 8 am to first booking start time and last booking end time to 6 pm, put to the free_time_slot_array if interval > 60 * 30.
5. Pick three time slot randomly from the free_time_slot_array and convert back to date time.

Hope it could work for you.